# How can I add a shortcut to printer settings to the Desktop Panel on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, printing, gnome-control-center

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 with GNOME Desktop. I'm looking for a way to add a Printers shortcut to the Desktop panel, because I always need to change printer settings.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The shortcuts of all settings are located at `/usr/share/applications`. You can copy the printer settings shortcut to the desktop with:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/system-config-printer.desktop ~/Desktop
```

Or use the GUI to copy it... You then have to make it executable, by *right-clicking it --> Properties --> Permissions tab --> Mark* '*allow executing file as program'.*

done.